# GAE Python - Ajax not returning value

Tags: python, ajax, google-app-engine

I am running a simple Ajax request to update a datetime object on the Google App Engine datastore, however for some reason it is not returning the value I am asking it to return. I have a similar script working for another job which has no issues, so I must be missing something small. I suspect it to be in the Javascript/Ajax code however I wasn't able to find it.

The form on the page submits values without any errors to a python script. This then updates and saves the datastore item without problems, and ends with:

```
self.response.out.write('test message')
```

The script that initiates this is following:

```
$('.set-date').submit(function () {
  var form = $(this);
  var key = form.attr('id').substr(4);
  var day = $('#SETDAY-' + key).val()
  var month = $('#SETMONTH-' + key).val()
  var dataString = 'reminderkey='+ key + '&setdate=' + day + '-' + month;

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/user/reminders/setdate",
      data: dataString,
      success: function(data) {
          $('#success-info span').text(data);
      }
  });
});
```

Finally, here's the HTML where the result is to be posted:

```
<div id="success-info" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
  <strong>It's done!</strong> <span></span>
</div>
```

As said, the python script updates and saves the database entry. No errors. However the 'test message' is not shown on the page, whereas with a similar script this works just fine. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE 1**
Maybe it helps to show the other script that actually works. It receives the same input from a python script and shows the same response successfully in the span within the exact same html code:

```
$('.activate-switch').on('switch-change', function (e, data) {
  var $element = $(data.el),
    value = data.value;
  var switchid = $element.attr('id')
  var key = switchid.substr(9);
  var dataString = 'reminderkey='+ key + '&status=' + value; 

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/user/reminders/activate",
      data: dataString,
      success: function(data) {
          $('#success-info span').text(data);
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: does the html and python endpoint in the same server? maybe you hit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing You can debug it from browser to see the request / response of the ajax request

Comment: What about the response code you are sending back? Implement 'error': function (data) { callback on your AJAX request and see if it gets called.